# Does KernelDensity.estimate in pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity work when input data is normally distributed?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

Does pyspark's KernelDensity.estimate work correctly on a dataset that is normally distributed? I get an error when I try that. I have filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20803 (KernelDensity.estimate in pyspark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity throws net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException when input data is normally distributed (no error when data is not normally distributed))

Example code:

```
vecRDD = sc.parallelize(colVec)
kd = KernelDensity()
kd.setSample(vecRDD)
kd.setBandwidth(3.0)
# Find density estimates for the given values
densities = kd.estimate(samplePoints)
```

When data is NOT Gaussian, I get for e.g.
5.6654703477e-05,0.000100010001,0.000100010001,0.000100010001,.....

For reference, using Scala, for Gaussian data,
Code:

```
vecRDD = sc.parallelize(colVec)
kd = new KernelDensity().setSample(vecRDD).setBandwidth(3.0)
// Find density estimates for the given values
densities = kd.estimate(samplePoints)
```

I get:
[0.04113814235801906,1.0994865517293571E-163,0.0,0.0,.....

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was able to track down the issue to a very minimal [test case](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20803?focusedCommentId=16177855&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16177855). If you're using Numpy in Python to generate the data in the RDD, then that's the problem!

```
import numpy as np
kd = KernelDensity()
kd.setSample(sc.parallelize([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])) # THIS WORKS
# kd.setSample(sc.parallelize([0.0, np.float32(1.0), 2.0, 3.0])) # THIS FAILS
kd.setBandwidth(0.35)
kd.estimate([0.0, 1.0])
```

If this was your issue as well, simply convert the Numpy data to Python base type until the [Spark issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20803) is fixed. You can do that by using the [np.asscalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html) function.